# Cannot read property 'props' of undefined calling parent function from child

Tags: reactjs

I get the error  - Cannot read property 'props' of undefined
not sure what i am doing wrong , i have posted the relevant code below.

calling parent function from child

PARENT

```
import CompleteSearchBar from '../Components/CompleteSearchBar';

export class home extends Component {

   
simplifiedFunction = () => {
    console.log("simplifiedFunction called")
  }

 

    render() {
        return (
<div>
<CompleteSearchBar 
simplifiedFunction = {this.simplifiedFunction} 
name="Sara"/>
) }

}
```

CHILD

```
export default function CompleteSearchBar(props) {
return (
<button 
onClick={() =>
  this.props.simplifiedFunction()}
>SEARCH
</button>
) 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try **props.simplifiedFunction()** without **this** since you are in a function not a class component

Comment: silly me, thanks that worked , says i have to wait 5 minutes to accept the answer